# Delphi 7 & indy 9 Buffer Reader issue, Not reading all Packets

Tags: delphi, sockets, tcp, indy-9

I have an Delphi app (Developed in Delphi 7 utilising indy 9) that connects to an Java Server application.

The communication is working perfectly in our Staging environment. The issue happens in our Production Environment.

I did a TCP dump and was able to track all the data packets, All the data is deliver onto the network interface card where the Delphi app is running. Our MTU is set as default on 1500

The total packet size is on average 15kb.

When the delphi app is reading the buffer it only reads a the fist few packets on the buffer and not the full response.

I was able to see that with on output to a text file of the data read from the buffer.

Upgrading to indy 10 is out of the question, We are in the process of migrating all our applications to a java environment.

Comment: What code is actually receiving packets and constructing the message to be processed?

Comment: The Delphi application

Comment: @user3641972: That is not what EWit was asking.  What does the APPLICATION CODE look like that is reading the packets and reconstructing the messages?  Please show your actual code that is using Indy to read the packets.  Also, please show the actual packets themselves, to verify that you are even using the correct code to read them.

Comment: You have neglected to ask a question.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the code with me, It's at the office, I will post it as soon as i'm in the office

Comment: @RobKennedy I need to found a solution to read the full buffer, as the application is not reading all the data from the buffer and this is resulting in failure of my transactions.

Comment: I'm sure you do. Why isn't your program reading the full buffer? Share what you learned from your debugging sessions. Then ask a question.

Comment: Without seeing your actual code, or the protocol it is trying to implement, we can only speculate as to why the code does not read full packets. My guess would be that you are simply using the wrong reading code for the protocol, and are thus not reading what you are supposed to be reading and get yourself out of sync.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of delphi/Indy-9. The following is just an observation on TCP applications.

In TCP based applications if there aren't application level markings(start and end) for the data exchanged one method usually followed is to encode the data length in say 2 or 4 bytes and prepend these bytes to actual data. The TCP application that receives such data should read the length bytes and keep reading until that many bytes arrive and then process further.

In your case -  may be the receiving application is interpreting the first few bytes as length but which actually is not. But payload. The value can be high. So the application isn't processing further because it hasn't received yet  that many bytes that it thought.

Comment: You're prollly right - protocol fail. I'm gonna upvote now 'cos this would be my guess too.